# How to avoid mouse events being triggered in the blank area of a UserControl after set the UserControl's scalling of RenderTransform?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have set UserControl's RenderTransform to a ScaleTransform(ScaleX = ScaleY = 500), and set the UserControl's Template to be a Line shape. However, when running the application, I noticed that the mouse events of UserControl are triggered when the mouse click or move in the blank area near the line.

When I set the scale to a smaller value,like ScaleX = ScaleY = 1, I don't encounter this issue.

Click in the blank area near the line
[image: Click in the blank area near the line]

Here is my code:

```
    <Grid>
        <UserControl PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UserControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <UserControl.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="500" ScaleY="500" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </UserControl.RenderTransform>
            <UserControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Line
                        Stroke="Lime"
                        StrokeThickness="0.01"
                        UseLayoutRounding="True"
                        X1="0.4"
                        X2="0.8"
                        Y1="0.3"
                        Y2="0.3" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Cross" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </UserControl.Template>
        </UserControl>
    </Grid>
```

My expectation is that when I set a larger scale value(ScaleX = ScaleY = 500 or larger), the UserControl should only respond to mouse events when clicking on the area of the line, and avoid triggering mouse events in the blank area.

UserControl only respond to mouse events when clicking on the area of the line
[image: UserControl only respond to mouse events when clicking on the area of the line]

Comment: here's my demo code in github: https://github.com/yao-xiaofei/ShapeTest

Comment: Reminds me of an old question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19324094/1136211

Comment: Very strange. I thought for sure changing this to a `LayoutTransform` would solve the issue but it doesn't. I think you might have to actually translate the mouse point using the transform and then do your own hit test.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your suggestion. It is indeed the same issue, and it appears to be a bug(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8708e340-f734-4cf4-b91d-28b49fee2b72/hittest-is-buggy-not-accurate-for-transformed-scaled-etc-visuals?forum=wpf ), and unfortunately, it has remained unresolved for over a decade. The workaround you mentioned is helpful for me.